# How to create a void method for retire

Tags: java

[whole qstn description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV6Pc.png)
[Need help creating the retireplayer method in this assigmnent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEOOb.png)

Help needed to create avoid retireplayer method in the image attached above

This is my class so far

public class Cricket implements  Sport {
int[] playerIds = new int[11]; ;

```
public Cricket() {

    for (int i = 0; i < playerIds.length; i++) {
        playerIds[i] = 1;

    }
    System.out.println("A new cricket team has been formed");
}

@Override
public void calculateAvgAge(int[] age) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < age.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + age[i];
    }
    float avgAGE = sum / playerIds.length;
    System.out.println("The average age of the team is " + String.format("%.2f", avgAGE));


}

@Override
public void retirePlayer(int id) {
    boolean c = false;
    boolean k = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < playerIds.length; i++){

        playerIds[id] = -1;
        c = true;
        if(playerIds[i]==id){
            k =true;
        }

    }
    if(c) System.out.println("Player with id: "+ id + " has retired");
    if(k) System.out.println("Player already retired");









}
```

}

This was my initial code for the method
Decptn: To create a retire player method(int id) assign -1 to playerid[id] which is my array used throught the whole class. i should print "player with id:{id} has retired" if the player has already retired i should print "Player already retired"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs through the array to find a matching id. if a match is found. it retires player and prints and returns the method. else if no match is found it prints no match found.

The problem with your code was that for each iteration of for loop, you assign each member of the array to -1, so you retired all players. You only retire the player if the id matches. That is what the if statement is for.

```
 public void retirePlayer(int id){
            for (int i=0; i<playerIds.length; i++) {
                if (playerIds[i] == id) {
                    playerIds[i] = -1;
                    System.out.println("The player with id: {"+id+"} has retired");
                    return;
                }
            }
    
            System.out.println("Player already retired");        
        }

//ignore above

public void retirePlayer(int id){
        //int id is an index!!
        if (id >11 || id < 1){
            System.out.println("Invalid player number!!");
            return;
        }
        if (playerIds[id-1] == 1) {
            playerIds[id-1] = -1;
            System.out.println("The player with id: {"+id+"} has retired");
        }else if (playerIds[id-1] == -1){
            System.out.println("Player already retired");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its only returning Player already retired! i want an output like : if i use incase id 1 then the output should be : "The player with id 1 has retired" and if i use it again should be "Player already retired"

Comment: wouldnt that mean that the player has already retired?

Comment: I dont think that would be possible without any helper parameters such as an extra int, or a field variable in your cricket class, because no where in your method are you keeping track of how many times you called a particular individuals id.

Comment: I think I might know what the problem is. The lack of details. I made the method thinking id was an actual id, but on looking at your question in further detail, i think the int id is in fact an index.

Comment: sure ! but right now am getting Index 11 out of bounds for length 11

Comment: Thats because of array indexing... arrays start from zero. zero to 10 is still 11.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate to find the player.  Per the task description (you really should translate the image to text in the question), the ID is the index into the underlying array.  Therefore you have random access to the retrirement state. Thus we can inspect and switch on the value.  We will either report they are already retired or we will mark them as retired and report that retirement.

```
public void retirePlayer(int id) {
  if (id < 0 || id >= playerIds.length) {
    System.err.println("Cannot retire player - ID is out of bounds: "+ id);
    return;
  }
  if (playerIds[id] == -1) {
    System.out.println("Player is already retired");
  } else {
    playerIds[id] = -1;
    System.out.printf("Player with id: %d has retired", id);
  }
}
```